# Typescript: this typing in object type

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
    get projections(): { [id: string]: this } { ... }
}

class B extends A {}

new B().projections // should be { [id: string]: B }
```

However, type script does not allow the `this` type in this position. Is there any way to express what I want? Or any reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: `this` refers to a specific instance of an object, not a class itself. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` can't be used in this way. Let me suggest a code to achieve what you want.

```
class A {
    get projections() { 
        // ...
        let result = {}; // <-- your return object
        return (<T>(obj: T): { [id: string]: T } => result)(this);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

new B().projections // => { [id: string]: B }
```

I'd not like to use the anonymous function but this was the way I found to get your result.

You can create a private help function on `A` to make the code more readable:

```
class A {
    private applyResult<T>(obj: T, result: { [id: string]: T }) {
        return result;
    }

    get projections() { 
        // ...
        let result = {}; // <-- your return object
        return this.applyResult(this, result);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

new B().projections // => { [id: string]: B }
```

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Nice answer. Funnily the `vscode` editor now infers exactly my suggested type annotation when I hover over the definition of `projections`. So is it really true that `projections` now has a type that is simply not expressible using an explicit type annotation? I somehow feel this is a flaw in the language then as I'm writing a type definition where I _have_ to make the type explicit.

Comment: That is the unique way I found to do it. You can use the command `tsc your_file.ts -d` to use the typescript compiler to extract the definition from this code. Unfortunately you will see a signature like: `... { [id: string]: this; }` that not works. Maybe you can do it in another way using generics.